# Answered Notification for Outbound call from an App - TWILIO

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

For Outbound Calls From An App to a Number,
  There are two legs - One between my browser and Twilio and the other between Twilio and the number to be dialled
  Can I set a webhook to trigger, on each callstatus value change (especially when the Call Status is in-progress) of the second leg and How?
**This is necessary so that I can start the timer and show hold button only after the customer picks up the phone** 
Any other idea to achieve this also Welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you dial out from [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js) you can send parameters into the request, such as the number, then Twilio will send your application a webhook with those parameters to find out what to do next. To dial a number, you would use the [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) verb and nest a [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number) within it.

With a `<Number>` you can register for webhook callbacks when certain events take place. You do so by setting a [`statusCallback` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback) to the URL that will receive the callback. By default the `statusCallback` URL will only receive the `completed` event when the call finishes, however you can register for more events using the [`statusCallbackEvent` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback-event).

The event you want to subscribe too is called "answered" and the TwiML you need is:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number statusCallback="http://example.com/calls/callback" statusCallbackEvent="answered">
      NUMBER TO DIAL
    </Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Awesome! Hope the rest of your app is going well too.

Comment: @philnash what is the status callback url???. I dont have a url. Iam running the code in python. How can I get the status in my code?

Comment: @Anesh take a read through this article, it should explain some things: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery-python

Comment: Thanks but I need to know the status of the outbound call. I read alll articles and gave ngrok http in status callback url, but iam not getting any information in my python environment.

Comment: I see you've asked a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54333673/how-to-know-the-status-of-outbound-calls), let's take this discussion over there.