# How to know the status of outbound calls?

Tags: python-3.x, twilio-api

I make a outbound call i.e I make a request to twilio to make a call to a number using twilio api. How to know if a person has picked up or rejected the call?. What is statuscallback url?..I dont have a url.

Comment: We were chatting on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419512/answered-notification-for-outbound-call-from-an-app-twilio/40423262?noredirect=1#comment95496179_40423262) but it seems like a better idea to cover this here. Can you share the code you're using?

Comment: `call=client_twilio.calls.create(status_callback="https://401d2bb8.ngrok.io",method='GET',to=number,from_="+19729759934",url="http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",status_callback_method='POST')`
 `print(call.sid)`.       This is the code iam using. I need to know the status of the outbound call in my output.

Comment: Ok, you need to set up a server to receive the status callback webhook. Have you done that?

Comment: No sir. How to setup a server?

Comment: I know this tutorial is about sending SMS messages, but the process for calls is the same, so I recommend you walk through this and see how you do: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery-python

Comment: Thank you. Let me check it and say if it works.

Comment: Should always keep running that flask code to get the status callback. When I run that, it says Running on http:/// (Press CTRL+C to quit)...should I give that http to the status callback?

Comment: You will need the server to be running to receive the webhook, yes

Comment: Iam still not getting the status. i gave ngrok http 5000 and copied the link to status callback url. Still when I `print(call.sid)` iam getting some random alpha numeric thing.

Comment: Please help me. I need to know the callback status

Comment: when you call `print(call.sid)` the `sid` is the unique ID for the call, so it is random numbers and letters. If you want the call status, try `call.status`. Sounds like it's all working for you so I'll write this up as an answer.

Comment: Thanks but iam getting the status 'queued' only. How do I know if the call is completed?

Comment: That's when you send the message or make the call. Did you set up the Flask app as [shown in the tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery-python?code-sample=code-handle-a-sms-statuscallback&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x)? Did you get ngrok set up? Did you use the ngrok URL to your Flask app as the `statusCallback` URL?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you make an outbound call you can register to receive status updates by setting the [`statusCallback` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#statuscallback) to a URL. When the call changes status, Twilio will send an HTTP request to the URL with details of the call and its current status.

To learn more about this, I recommend following [this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery-python). It covers delivery notifications for SMS messages, but the process is exactly the same for calls.